# link_to issue with calling another method ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a products database i'm accessing and outputting some info on /products/show

I'm trying to add a link_to in the loop to go to the action add_to_cart so I can simulate an add to cart feature. Right now I'm just trying to get the id of the corresponding record when the link is clicked and then I want to do another loop in the shopping cart section to output that record in a table row.

**products_controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    show
    render 'show'
  end

  def show
    @products = Product.order("products.name ASC")
  end

  def add_to_cart
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
<div id="shoppingCart">
  <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="cartContainer" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>

<div class="large-12 columns">
  <div class="row">
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
        <div class="large-3 columns panel radius prodContainer" style="height: 600px">    <h2 class="prodTitle"><%= product.name %></h2><br><h3 class="prodUnitPrice">$<%= product.unit_price %></h3><br>ID: <%= product.id %><br><br>
    <p class="prodDesc"><%= product.description %></p>
    <!-- Add to Cart Link -->
    <%= link_to("Add to Cart", {:action => add_to_cart, :id => product.id}, :class => 'button radius') %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Catalog::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :home do
    get 'home/index'
  end

  resources :products do
    get 'products/show'
    get 'products/add_to_cart'
  end

  root :to => 'home#index'

  get ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

**The error I'm getting:**

```
undefined local variable or method `add_to_cart' for #<#<Class:0x40c31b8>:0x3988f08>
```

I'm still learning so it's not entirely clear to me

**here is what the command put out:**

```
c:\Sites\Catalog>bundle exec rake routes | grep add_to_cart
product_products_add_to_cart GET    /products/:product_id/products/add_to_cart(.
:format) products#add_to_cart
```

Comment: please, show us `rake routes | grep add_to_cart`. and try `add_to_cart_path` instead `add_to_cart`

Comment: maybe it doesn't know which controller to route too, try adding `:controller => products`

Comment: when i add :controller => products i get undefined local variable or method `products' for #<#<Class:0x40bfa98>:0x435d890>. same thing with add_to_cart_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
<%= link_to("Add to Cart", {:action => add_to_cart, :id => product.id}, :class => 'button radius') %>
```

To this:

```
<%= link_to("Add to Cart", {:action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product.id}, :class => 'button radius') %>
```

You had forgotten to enclose the name of the action within quotes and so it was being interpreted as a local variable or method.

Comment: Ah thank, you that worked. Now when I click the link i get a URL such as http://localhost:3000/products/add_to_cart/1

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't look like it is going to work anyway! I can't update show after i click the button as the instance variables in show for the add to cart part aren't ready until the button is clicked